# Clearing TextView in Android

Tags: android

I'm facing this problem with TextView. It is not erasing the previous instances of data.

When I'm running my application in emulator it displays output data in TextView. That's fine. But when I'm clicking back button in my emulator and re opening the application it does not clear the previous data. Instead it appends the data to already existing data.

Any help is appreciated.

My code is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
{

   private TextView mTextView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_test);
       new Thread(new TestLocalHost()).start();
   }

   private class TestLocalHost implements Runnable 
   {
       @Override
       public void run() 
       {
        final String s = JSONParser.doGet("http://192.168.0.107:15071/GetResult.ashx?op=getInfo",null);
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
            {
               @Override
               public void run() 
               {    
                   mTextView.setText(s);    
               }
           });
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have the string you're expecting already duplicated in `String s`?

Comment: @ssantos yes mate I'm checking that. Actually it is getting data from database which is say 10 quantity. But the moment i press back and execute it again it wont erase the previous. It shows me 20 data values

Comment: So the second time you enter, `s` gets `10` value, but `mTextView` shows 20, right?

Comment: I'm sorry @ssantos you are right, the string s itself carries 20 data the next time it passes it to the TextView. So TextView is innocent here....Thanks

Comment: Glad you found out the problem :)

Comment: Thanks @ssantos its working now. How insane could i be not to figure out such a silly thing. But then thanks to you mate... :)

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because your app still lives in the emulator memory, you need to force kill it if you want your app to run again from scratch.

You should click on the "running processes" button and swipe left/right the app process.

In the scenario that you described the activity wasn't destroyed yet, and when you reopen it only its onResume() method is being called.